In what sense is $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb P^1)$ a scheme?
$\newcommand{\Aut}{\operatorname{Aut}}\newcommand{\P}{\mathbb P}$ Let $\P^1=\operatorname{Proj}(\mathbb C[x_0,x_1])$, then I am trying to understand how $\Aut(\P^1)$ is a scheme/group scheme (if this even makes sense I am honestly a bit confused here).
So since $\P^1$ is a special variety, I believe there is a bijection between scheme morphisms $\P^1\rightarrow \P^1$ (maybe they also have to commute with the natural morphism $\P^1\rightarrow \operatorname{Spec}\mathbb C$?) and certain set maps on closed points $|\P^1|\rightarrow |\P^1|$. After identifying the closed points with equivalence classes $[z_1,z_2]$, these certain set maps are of the form
\begin{align}
[z_1,z_2]&\longmapsto[f_1(z_1,z_2),f_2(z_1,z_2)]
\end{align}
where $f_1$ and $f_2$ are homogenous polynomials of the same degree, and their set of zeros over $\mathbb C^2$ are disjoint.
If we wish to restrict ourselves to the invertible morphisms, then we need $f_1$ and $f_2$ to be invertible polynomials but the only such polynomials are linear so we have that automorphisms are of the form:
\begin{align}
[z_1,z_2]\longmapsto[az_1+bz_2,cz_1+dz_2]
\end{align}
but this is matrix multiplication so for this to be invertible we need $ad-bc\neq 1$, and morphisms are equivalent up to $\mathbb C^{\times}$ so we have naturally identified $\Aut(\P^1)$ with $PGL(2)$ as groups, but how do we then identify $\Aut(\P^1)$ with a scheme? It seems to me that $PGL(2)$ is a complex Lie group so it's usual topology does not carry a scheme structure, and I think we would probably need to add at least one point (a generic point) so that it could naturally inherit the structure of a scheme in the first place.
Is it just that there exists some $\mathbb C$-scheme $X$ so that it's closed/$\mathbb C$points are naturally identified with the $\Aut(\P^1)$, sort of how $\P^1$ is a scheme but it's $\mathbb C$ points are naturally identified with $\mathbb C\P^1$? If so how do we define such a scheme/construct it?

The natural idea is to consider the functor mapping a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra $R$ to the set of $R$-scheme automorphisms of $\mathbb{P}^1_R$.

@Aphelli Can you elaborate?

If this functor is representable by a scheme, this scheme is a natural candidate for a scheme of automorphisms of $\mathbb{P}^1$, isn’t it?

@Aphelli I guess I agree with that since then the $\mathbb C$ points would be automorphisms of $\mathbb P^1$, but how do we know this is representable as a scheme?

I’m not sure we do, in general situations – but it’s still worth thinking about, and perhaps it works here (try computing it!).

Note also that $PGL(2)$ is absolutely a scheme – you can view it as the open subscheme of $\mathbb{P}^3$ with homogeneous coordinates $[a:b:c:d]$ where $ad-bc \neq 0$.

See for instance here and here - if those resolve your question, please let me know.

@Aphelli I agree that that determines a an open subscheme of $\mathbb P^3$ who’s $\mathbb C$ points can be naturally identified with elements of $PGL(2)$, but I don’t agree that makes $PGL(2)$ a scheme.

@KReiser I’m a bit confused by your answers in the linked questions; I would’ve expected the correct scheme corresponding to $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb P^1)$ would be a variety over $\mathbb C$, but you’ve defined them as schemes over $\mathbb Z$?

@Chris it's simple enough to base change along the unique map $\Bbb Z\to \Bbb C$. If you're looking at $\Bbb C$-points, you get the same answer in both cases. (Also, I only wrote an answer at one of those links.)

Here's a rough sketch, I'm afraid I don't know where to direct you for more details. The sense in which $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{P}^1)$ is a scheme is that it has a functor of points; it's not important that we work over $\mathbb{C}$ here so allow me to work over $\mathbb{Z}$. Then if $X$ is any scheme, the functor of points of $\text{Aut}(X)$ sends a commutative ring $R$ to the automorphism group of the base change $X_R$ of $X$ to $R$, as a scheme over $R$; that is, we have
$$\text{Aut}(X)(R) \cong \text{Aut}_{\text{Sch}/R}(X_R).$$
So the functor of points of $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{P}^1)$ sends a commutative ring $R$ to the automorphism group of $\mathbb{P}^1_R$, regarded as an $R$-scheme. This works out to be $PGL_2(R)$, suitably understood (the usual definition has to be modified a bit if $R$ is not a field); so this functor is not only representable by a (group) scheme but even by an affine (group) scheme, namely $PGL_2$. This won't be true in general; e.g. I think $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{A}^2)$ is not a scheme, or at the very least not a scheme of finite type (see e.g. this MO discussion).
KReiser's comments don't answer your question because they don't explain in what sense $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{P}^1)$, which a priori is only a group (in sets), can be identified with $PGL_2$, which is a scheme, since of course a scheme is not determined by its $\mathbb{C}$-points in general.
This is actually a special case of a general definition one can write down in any category with finite products of an "automorphism object," closely analogous to the definition of an exponential object. Somewhat surprisingly there doesn't appear to be an nLab article about this.

Ok so $PGL_2$ is the group scheme which is represented by the functor $R\mapsto PGL_2(R)$, but is not actually the group $PGL_2$ which I understand to be a quotient of the general linear group? And the reason we call this group scheme the automorphism group of $\mathbb P^1$ is because if we plug $R$ into this functor of points we get the automorphism group of $\mathbb P^1_R=\operatorname{Proj}R[x_0,x_1]$?

@Chris: $PGL_2$ is the quotient of $GL_2$ by scalars in a suitable categorical sense (e.g. in the category of affine group schemes, and maybe also in the category of fppf sheaves or something like that). One has to be careful here because this quotient is not taken pointwise (same as with sheaves), so it is not true that $PGL_2(R)$ is the quotient of $GL_2(R)$ by scalars in general. And yes, although I think that definition of $\mathbb{P}^1_R$ also has to be modified in general if $R$ is not a field. Admittedly I am not an expert in this stuff.

@Qiachu Yuan I guess I more meant that when I think of $PGL_2$ I think of it as an actual group and potentially a Lie group if the group is over $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$, but from what I understand, a group scheme is not actually a group in the traditional sense since it often times has weird extra points right?

@Chris: well, it has a functor of points. It's a lot simpler to start this discussion with $GL_2$: you can think of it as a real Lie group $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ or as a complex Lie group $GL_2(\mathbb{C})$, but as a group scheme it has a whole functor of points, namely $R \mapsto GL_2(R)$. This functor is representable by an affine scheme, namely $\text{Spec } \mathbb{Z}[x_{11}, x_{12}, x_{21}, x_{22}][\det^{-1}]$ where $x_{ij}$ are the four entries of a $2 \times 2$ matrix and $\det$ is its determinant. So $GL_2$ is what is called an affine group scheme.

$PGL_2$ is also an affine group scheme but a slightly more complicated one; IIRC it works out to be the spectrum of the subring of $\mathbb{Z}[x_{11}, x_{12}, x_{21}, x_{22}][\det^{-1}]$ consisting of elements of degree $0$. Taking the subring here corresponds to taking the quotient of $GL_2$ on the scheme side.

Group schemes are a good place to advertise the virtues of thinking in terms of functor of points as opposed to thinking in terms of the Zariski spectrum. The Zariski spectrum has a lot of strange points in it and it's unclear why one would write down these points from first principles (they do not correspond to specific automorphisms, eg). But the functor of points in this case is much easier and more conceptual to describe.

Yaun So just to be clear, the scheme $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb P^1)$ is the one associated to some representable functor, and so its underlying set is not actually the group of automorphism of $\mathbb P^1$, but instead its $\mathbb C $ points are? Have I understood this correctly?

@Chris: yes, the underlying set of the scheme is not even a group at all, it's just not a very well-behaved notion. But the $\mathbb{C}$ points are, by definition, the automorphism group of $\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{C}}$, which as you know is $PGL_2(\mathbb{C})$.
